# Mostrar loading hasta que se cargue la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css3

Buenos días,

Estoy desarrollando mi sitio web pero no tengo conocimientos en JavaScript y no se cómo hacer algo que ustedes por ahí si...

Tengo transiciones (fadein) que van mostrando los elementos dentro del body (ej: el header aparece desde arriba, el main desde abajo). El problema es que el main contiene fotografías un poco pesada, tardan en cargarse, y la transición se produce igual, cuando las imágenes no están cargadas completamente, y se ve mal. Por ejemplo, [esta página](http://huntt.tkdemos.com) no muestra el contenido hasta que no esta cargado completamente, para que las transiciones muestren correcta y ordenadamente todo el contenido.

Entonces lo que quiero hacer es mostrar un gif loading hasta que todo el contenido dentro del body este cargado, y ahí recién mostrarla y que las transiciones que hice con CSS3 muestren el contenido correctamente. Algo parecido a lo que hace [este jQuery plugin](http://git.blivesta.com/animsition). Ustedes me dirán, ¿por qué no usas el plugin ese? la razón es que no quiero sobrecargar mi página con plugins externos y hacer yo mismo las cosas.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes mirarte esto para empezar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load. Podrías poner una capa con un gif hasta que termine de cargar la página y entonces ocultarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la libreria queryloader2 [Plugin queryloader2](https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/)

Con esto cargara el contenido antes de mostrarlo, espero te sirva.

```js
$("body").queryLoader2({
  barColor: "#555566",
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  percentage: true,
  barHeight: 1,
  completeAnimation: "grow",
  minimumTime: 100,
  onLoadComplete: hidePreLoader
});

function hidePreLoader() {
  $("#precarga").hide();
}
```

```css
/* Preload */
#precarga {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
}



/*Body*/
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #778899;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.queryloader2/3.2.2/jquery.queryloader2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="precarga"></div>

  <div id="contenido">
    <h1>Contenido de la Pagina</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Con Jquery puedes detectar que cargó la pagina con jQuery(window).load

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
   //ya cargo la pagina 
   //Oculta o quita el gif de loading
   //Inicia los fade's
});
```

[Documentación](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Se agradecería que explicaran por que la puntuación negativa